# Derivation from Solow-type neoclassical growth equation?

Tags: economic-growth, production-function, solow, population-economics

[image]In Chapter 6 of the 12th edition of "Economic Development" by Michael P. Todaro & Stephen C. Smith, an equation is introduced to illustrate the consequences of rapid population growth, derived from 'the standard Solow-type neoclassical growth equation'. I understand the components individually, but I'm struggling with the derivation process from the standard production function
Y=f(K,L,R,T).

Could someone kindly provide insight into how this equation is derived? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is just a logaritmization of a Cobb-Douglas type production function assuming small and constant growth rates. For small growth rates $x$
$$
x \approx \ln(1+x).
$$
The Cobb-Douglas type production function is
$$
Y = AK^{\alpha}L^{1-\alpha}.
$$
Assuming constant growth of the variables you have
$$
Y(1+y) = A(1+a)\left(K(1+k)\right)^{\alpha}\left(L(1+l)\right)^{1-\alpha},
$$
and so
$$
1+y = (1+a)(1+k)^{\alpha}(1+l)^{1-\alpha}.
$$
Taking the logarithm of this you get
$$
\ln(1+y) = \ln(1+a) + \alpha\ln(1+k) + (1-\alpha)\ln(1+l).
$$
Using the logarithmic approximation
$$
y \approx a + \alpha k + (1-\alpha)l,
$$
and after some algebraic magic
$$
y - l \approx a + \alpha (k - l).
$$
The notation for $a$ was $t$ in your equation, but otherwise we got it!

---

P.s.: I have not seen a Solow model's production function include $R$ (resources) before, so I don't know how that would change things, but apparently it didn't?